# Не получается завершить установку Kali Linux на Virtual Box, MacOS

Tags: macos, virtualbox, kali-linux

Проблема возникает не первый раз: устанавливаю iso образ Kali Linux на Virtual Box, всё идёт хорошо но на финальном этапе самой установки процессор начинает сильно греться и в какой-то момент загрузка останавливается, а затем появляется уведомление о том, что Virtual Box не отвечает.
В этот раз зависание произошло на этапе
Select and install software
и Unpacking libjs-jquery-ui(amd64) под строкой загрузки.

Пробовала:

- оставлять всё как есть и дожидаться отклика программы;
- закрывала всё кроме VB и самой машины с кали;
- перезагрузка устройства;
- переустановка как самого Kali Linux, так и Virtual Box;
- чистила память (как

  оперативку, так и хранилище).

Никаких результатов это не дало, программа виснет, пока не сделаешь force quit.
Прошерстила форум и массу других статей в гугле, но не нашла даже описания такой же проблемы, не то чтобы причины или решения.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, в чём хотя бы могут быть причины такого зависания?

ОС: MacOS Monterey 12.4
Версия VB: 6.140
Версия Kali: 2022.3, разрядность 64bit

Буду благодарна за любую помощь.